# Detect duplicate file extensions

Tags: c#

What is the best way for detecting duplicate file extensions on an image file? (`imageName.tif.jpg`). In order to assure a jpg the file extension I have to work with auto appends .jpg to the end on ingestion.

I thought about iterating over a collection known file extensions and checking if the filename contains that extension. Or checking the first index of period and last but if the image name for whatever reason is `my.test.tif.jpg`. Ultimately once I detect the duplicate extension, I want to purge the last .jpg from it.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

        if (fileName != null)
        {
            int firstFileExtPos = fileName.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            int lastFileExtPos = fileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);

            if (firstFileExtPos != lastFileExtPos)
            {
                path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 4);
            }
        }

        return path;
```

Comment: `path.Length - 4` keep in mind not all image file extensions are 3 characters plus a dot (4 characters). There's JPEG, TIFF, and probably a few others I can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Let's say the file does have the extension "jpg" and "tif" (`xyz.tif.jpg`) which extension would you remove? Wouldn't you need to identify the real file type before you can decide which one doesn't apply?

Comment: The last .jpg would be trimmed. Some case it could even be .jpg.jpg. The ingester always appends ".jpg" to the end so it is safe to assume a length of 4 for the trim.

Comment: @egordon21 Any way to fix the "ingester" rather than making a band-aid fix like this?

Comment: Why don't you use `Path.GetExtension()` method to find the extension.

Comment: The image type is uploaded as a tif, and the ingester converts it to a jpg and slaps that extension on the end. The workflow here is the user then posts a flat file saying they want to link up image.tif to a record, and I needed a safe way of comparing image.tif == image.tif.jpg without some contains hacks or starts with that could fail. In some cases the image name could have 1 extension thus nothing special would need to happen.

Comment: Path.GetExtension() only returns .jpg in this case. the .tif is a part of the filename at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to do this is to first do a test like:

```
ExtraExtension = Path.GetExtension(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName))
```

to see if there is even an extra extension.

You can then test that against a list of known extensions, if so, you just remove the last extension:

```
fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
```

Comment: Thanks, very clean and simple. I like the Regex answer as well, but don't want to maintain/localize all valid image extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex (add as many extensions as you want using `|` separator):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(fileName, @"\.(tif|jpg|gif|bmp)\.jpg$"))
    path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is pretty elegant (and general purpose):

```
static string PurgeRedundantExtensions( string fileName , params string[] extensions )
{
  if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "fileName"               ) ;
  if ( extensions.Length < 1               ) throw new ArgumentException(     "no extensions supplied" ) ;

  List<segments> segments      =  fileName.Split('.') ;
  int            last          =  segments.Length - 1 ;
  bool           hasRedundancy =  segments.Length > 2
                               && extensions.Contains( segments[ last   ] , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
                               && extensions.Contains( segments[ last-1 ] , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
                               ;

  if ( hasRedundancy )
  {
    segments.RemoveAt(last) ;
  }

  string purged = string.Join( "." , segments ) ;
}
```

So you can say something like

```
string raw     = "foobar.gif.jpg" ;
string cleaned = PurgeRedundantExtensions( raw ,
                   "gif" , "jpg" , "jpeg" , "bmp" , "png" , "tiff" , "tif"
                   ) ;
```

and get back

```
foobar.gif
```

Comment: This is good as well. I like that it ignores potential noise in the filename if periods exist by only evaluating the last two occurrences on the segments indexer.